# When blending two illumination together, will some of the "frequency components" cancel each other out?

Tags: optics, frequency

When I'm reading about color spaces on wikipedia, I noticed that it only concerns about the power spectral only distribution of a illumination without caring about the phases. I wonder if some frequency components of the light would cancel out, why only using power distribution is enough?

If two illuminations are not coherent, then how exactly would their power distributions merge?

Comment: usually the sources are not coherent

Comment: Photons never cancel each other ... they are always absorbed. In the EM field they do superimpose ... like water waves they reemerge.